# How to differentiate App Store, TestFlight, and IPA installs on iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, ipa

I have an iOS app and need a way to determine programmatically if the app was installed from the App Store, from TestFlight, or from an IPA file from the internet.

I've tried checking the last part of the app store receipt url as some people have suggested regarding different types of app installs, but both IPA files and TestFlight installs have "sandboxReceipt" as the last path component of the receipt url.

Expected results are, of course, the ability to determine how my app was installed.

Comment: It may help if you can give a rough idea of why you need to know the difference.

Comment: My goal is to have a test mode indicator in the app for TestFlight.